# Agrupar en Pandas, seleccionar mínimo de una columna y sumar datos de otra columna

Tags: pandas, group-by

No estoy encontrando la forma de organizar el siguiente dataframe en Pandas para que me muestre toda la información que necesito.
Tengo el siguiente dataframe:

```
    Fecha   ID  Nombre  Doc Doc2    Prod    Cantidad

0   2021-03-06 00:00:00 1   Lolo    123 1   1564    1
1   2021-03-06 00:00:00 1   Lolo    123 1   15665   1
2   2021-03-06 00:00:00 1   Lolo    123 1   1674    1
3   2021-03-06 00:00:00 2   Momo    125 1   1568    1
4   2021-03-06 00:00:00 2   Momo    125 1   1568    1
5   2021-03-06 00:00:00 3   PePe    136 2   1568    1
6   2021-03-06 00:00:00 3   PePe    136 2   1678    1
7   2021-03-06 00:00:00 4   Lolo    123 1   1674    1
8   2021-03-06 00:00:00 5   Coco    125 2   1568    1
9   2021-03-07 00:00:00 6   Lolo    123 1   15665   1
```

Ahora necesito sumar la `Cantidad` de `Prod` para una misma fecha para cada persona, por ejemplo Lolo, tiene las filas 0, 1, 2 y 4 el mismo dia. La forma que encontré de hacerlo fue con `groupby` luego de concatenar la `Fecha` + `Doc` + `Doc2`, que fue la única forma que encontré para poder agrupar y separar la misma persona por diferente fecha. El código es el siguiente:

```
df['Concat'] = df['Doc'] + df['Doc2'] + df['Fecha'].str[:-9].str.replace('-','')

gb = df.groupby(['Concat', 'Fecha', 'Nombre', 'Doc', 'Doc2', 'Prod'],
                as_index=False)[['Cantidad']].sum()
```

y obtengo este resultado:

```
Concat  Fecha   Nombre  Doc Doc2    Prod    Cantidad
0   123120210306    2021-03-06 00:00:00 Lolo    123 1   1564    1
1   123120210306    2021-03-06 00:00:00 Lolo    123 1   1674    2
2   123120210306    2021-03-06 00:00:00 Lolo    123 1   15665   1
3   123120210307    2021-03-07 00:00:00 Lolo    123 1   15665   1
4   125120210306    2021-03-06 00:00:00 Momo    125 1   1568    2
5   125220210306    2021-03-06 00:00:00 Coco    125 2   1568    1
6   136220210306    2021-03-06 00:00:00 PePe    136 2   1568    1
7   136220210306    2021-03-06 00:00:00 PePe    136 2   1678    1
```

La agrupación es correcta, el problema es cuando quiero poner en el dataframe el `ID`  y que selecciones el mínimo ID de la fecha, que es este caso para "Lolo" es 1 (tiene 1 y 4 ese día en el ejemplo).

Cada vez que pongo el `ID` en `groupby`, deja de agruparme por cantidad.

Alguien me puede guiar en como llegar a la solución? El resultado debería ser así:

```
Concat  Fecha   ID  Nombre  Doc Doc2    Prod    Cantidad
0   123120210306    2021-03-06 00:00:00 1   Lolo    123 1   1564    1
1   123120210306    2021-03-06 00:00:00 1   Lolo    123 1   1674    2
2   123120210306    2021-03-06 00:00:00 1   Lolo    123 1   15665   1
3   123120210307    2021-03-07 00:00:00 6   Lolo    123 1   15665   1
4   125120210306    2021-03-06 00:00:00 2   Momo    125 1   1568    2
5   125220210306    2021-03-06 00:00:00 5   Coco    125 2   1568    1
6   136220210306    2021-03-06 00:00:00 3   PePe    136 2   1568    1
7   136220210306    2021-03-06 00:00:00 3   PePe    136 2   1678    1
```

Gracias.

Comment: LoLo corresponde a las 0,1,2,7 y si lo sumas deberá dar 4 o no?

Comment: Da 4 el total, pero por producto da 1,2,1 como resulta de la agrupación inicial. El tema que no encuentro solución como elegir el ID minimo de la fecha

Comment: si sabes que al hacer la columna `Concat` estas haciendo operaciones con enteros y string?

Comment: si, fue la unica forma que encontre para poder agrupar correctamente los usuarios, dado que el problema esta en los ID con la misma fecha. Distinta fecha el usuario puede tener otro ID nuevo.

Comment: Me refiero a que la operavion que haces es incorrecta

Comment: Disculpa, no entendi el comentario anterior. Cuando importo el df desde excel, las columnas de Fecha, Doc y Doc2 las transformo a strings, de modo de poder concatenarlas todas.

Comment: Haa.. disculpa, en un momento te doy una respuesta

Comment: No hya problema!! yo estoy hace 1 dia obteniendo puros errores o info que no me sirve para nada... y no veo la salida al final del tunel..

Answer (score 0):

Por si alguien necesita ayuda similar, la forma que me ayudaron a hacerlo e la siguiente:

```
# se crea un dataframe que establece el ID minimo del dia
df_min_id = df.groupby('Concat', as_index=False)['ID'].min()

df_min_id = df_min_id.rename(columns={'ID': 'min_ID'})

# luego se concatenan ambos dataframes

df = df.merge(df_min_id, on='Concat', how='left')
```

Despues se puede agrupar para tener el resultado deseado.
Saludos